# Saving Name/Value pair per line to a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have below pattern to fetch from a file:

```
....Name1:Value1.....Name2:Value2....Name3:Value3.....
....Name4:Value4.....Name5:Value5....Name6:Value6.....
```

I have multiple lines like below (myJSONString) form the file I am reading.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class removeMe { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String myJSONString = "{\"message\":{\"method\":\"Collect\",\"params\":{\"args\":{\"data\":{\"columnNumber\":1,\"lineNumber\":1,\"url\":\"http://localhost/MyScript.php\"},\"fileName\":\"http://localhost/MyScript.js\"},\"cPat\":\"tools\",\"dur\":182,\"name\":\"copile\",\"ph\":\"X\",\"pid\":11744,\"tdur\":145,\"tid\":12488,\"ts\":369069849845.0,\"tts\":299168}}}";

        String patternString = "(fileName\":\"|dur\":|tdur\":)([^\",]*)";

        List<Map<String,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();

        Collections.addAll(mapList, map1, map2,....);

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternString).matcher(myJSONString);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            map1.put(matcher.group(1).replaceAll(("\".*"),""),matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a map like map1 every time I read and grab values from the line. Then add it to the array list.

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression rather than a JSON parser?

Comment: You have a JSON string. Convert it to a java JSON object.

Comment: Well, that's how the return type is consumed by the main class, i.e an array list. Also, I need to do manipulation on the map like find max of dur and tdur for same filename. So I think I need to have map values for the token found in each line. Suggest if you think otherwise.

Comment: I could do this using a MultiMap as below:

`Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();`
.........
`multimap.put(matcher.group(1).replaceAll(("\".*"),""),matcher.group(2));`